# Altering tables with lock/unlock

Tags: mysql

could someone explain why I'm receiving this error:

```
Table 'last' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

Here is the queries executed one after another:

```
LOCK TABLES last WRITE;
DELETE FROM last WHERE id < '30';
ALTER TABLE last DROP id;
ALTER TABLE last ADD COLUMN `id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The error points on line that adds column (id), however if I put unlock statement just after delete - everything works without errors. Is it true that I cant just unlock ONE table last? It gives me errors with other tables, saying the same thing "Table was not locked with LOCK TABLES"

Comment: A ALTER TABLE statement automatically automatically unlocks a table

Comment: But why it gives that error then on 2nd ALTER query?

Comment: ok, so I neeed just to remove the last unlock statement I guess?

Comment: removed last unlock , it didnt help, still:      Table 'last' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html:

> If you use ALTER TABLE on a locked table, it may become unlocked. For example, if you attempt a second ALTER TABLE operation, the result may be an error Table 'tbl_name' was not locked with LOCK TABLES. To handle this, lock the table again prior to the second alteration. See also Section C.5.7.1, “Problems with ALTER TABLE”.